# Flow for JSF from JSP to Java class

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I am new to JSF (Have Fair knowledge in Struts) have tried some examples of JSF from internet and i have some doubts regarding the flow.

The example is some thing like below

`Login.xhtml`

```
<div>
    <h:panelGrid columns="2">
        <h:outputText value="Name"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputText value="#{loginBean.name}"></h:inputText>
        <h:outputText value="Password"></h:outputText>
        <h:inputSecret value="#{loginBean.password}"></h:inputSecret>
        <h:commandButton value="Login" action="login"></h:commandButton>
    </h:panelGrid>
</div>
```

`faces-config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<faces-config
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd"
    version="2.0">
    <managed-bean>
        <managed-bean-name>loginBean</managed-bean-name>
        <managed-bean-class>com.tutorial.LoginBean</managed-bean-class>
        <managed-bean-scope>session</managed-bean-scope>
    </managed-bean>
    <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>template/Login.xhtml</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/template/Login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>login</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>/template/Welcome.xhtml</to-view-id>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>

</faces-config>
```

`LoginBean:`

```
package com.tutorial;

public class LoginBean
{
    private String name;
    private String password;


    public String getName ()
    {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName (final String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }


    public String getPassword ()
    {
        return password;
    }


    public void setPassword (final String password)
    {
        this.password = password;
    }
}
```

Flow is that in login page we will give username and password and it will go to welcome page and will display the name

Listing out my queries below PLEASE help me in to figuer these things and get a better understanding of JSF

1. In struts we will have code something like below 
   `<action path="/LoginAction" type="com.app.action.LoginAction" name="LoginForm">`
   so for this "LoginAction" it will go to the LoginAction class and the bean or DTO will be LoginForm. in the above faces-config.xml the login.jsp is not linked to any bean class.
2. In struts we have execute method. do we have any default method in JSF like that ?
3. In JSF if we have a requirement like "when we click on a button in JSP the control should go to a java class and based on authentication in java we will go the success or failure page". what should be the configaration in `faces-config.xml`? in `<navigation>` tag ther is only tag with `<to-view>` (which means a JSP to my understanding) what should we do if the control should go to java class.

Comment: You need to pass through an up-to-date tutorial on JSF2 to gain the understanding you desire. By the way, the last two paragraphs are very informative!

Answer (score 1):

> *in the above faces-config.xml the login.jsp is not linked to any bean class.*

I'm not sure why that's necessary. JSF is component based, not request based.

---

> *In struts we have execute method. do we have any default method in JSF like that ?*

Nope, you've the full freedom to bind the `action` attribute of a command component to any arbitrary method of the backing bean.

E.g.

```
<h:commandButton value="Login" action="#{loginBean.submit}" />
```

with

```
public String submit() {
    // Do your thing here.
    // ...

    return "login";
}
```

Note that the method name is fully free to your choice. You can also use `#{loginBean.login}` with a `public String login()` method. I'm not sure why you would be restricted to a single predefined action name. JSF is component based, not request based.

---

> *"when we click on a button in JSP the control should go to a java class and based on authentication in java we will go the success or failure page". what should be the configaration in faces-config.xml? in  tag ther is only tag with  (which means a JSP to my understanding) what should we do if the control should go to java class.*

Create another `<navigation-case>`

```
<navigation-case>
    <from-outcome>error</from-outcome>
    <to-view-id>/template/Error.xhtml</to-view-id>
</navigation-case>
```

and handle accordingly in the action method:

```
public String submit() {
    // Do your thing here.
    // ...

    if (success) {
        return "login";
    } else {
        return "error";
    }
}
```

Noted should be that navigation cases are soo JSF 1.x. On JSF 2.x they are not necessary anymore. Just get rid of the whole `<navigation-rule>` block in `faces-config.xml` and make use of JSF implicit navigation feature.

```
    if (success) {
        return "/template/Welcome";
    } else {
        return "/template/Error";
    }
```

#### See also:

- [Communication in JSF 2.0](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html)